How to install and manage multiple python versions globally using Rye?
I'm trying to use Rye to manage multiple Python versions on my system globally. I want to avoid using Pyenv or similar tools, as I know they work, but I prefer to use Rye for this task. I aim to handle Python versions at the system level, not for a specific environment or project.
Could someone please provide a detailed guide on how to:

Install different Python versions globally using Rye.

Set a specific Python version as the global default.

verify the installed versions and the global version set.


